# Python: crawling data with mechanize: what to do when the fields don't have names?

Tags: python, web-crawler

Trying to use mechanize in Python, I am stucked because the fields I am trying to submit don't have names.

On the mechanize tutorial, it is said:

```
br.select_form(name="order")
# Browser passes through unknown attributes (including methods)
# to the selected HTMLForm.
br["cheeses"] = ["mozzarella", "caerphilly"]  # (the method here is __setitem__)
```

This is fine, but in my case the controls don't have name. Here is the code I run to ensure that:

```
resp = br.open("http://www.facebook.com/find-friends/browser/")
forms = ParseResponse(resp)
form = forms[2]  # I know I have to select form 2
for control in forms[0].controls:
    print control.name, control.type
```

And here is what I am getting (partially):

```
fb_dtsg hidden
friends_ids[] checkbox
None button
None hidden
None text
hometown_ids[] checkbox
None button
None hidden
None text
city_ids[] checkbox
None button
None hidden
None text
highschool_ids[] checkbox
None button
None hidden
None text
college_ids[] checkbox
```

So I am stucked here, as I can't apply the example from the tutorial (what I'd like to do is something like:

```
br['hometown'] = 'some town'
```

Does someone have a clue?

Thanks

Comment: I know that you can select forms by number by calling `form = br.select_form(nr=2)`, which selects the second form. Perhaps that would work with your controls as well?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Yes that's right! I dont know why I didnt think of it before. It's explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359817/how-do-you-select-choices-in-a-form-using-python

Answer (score 1):

I originally posted this as a comment, but as it turns out to be the answer, I am re-posting it as an answer (Thanks @OP for the link to the question cited here).

According to [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359817/how-do-you-select-choices-in-a-form-using-python), you should be able to select the controls by index as well:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open('http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp')
myControl = forms[N].controls[n]
```

In response to the comment "Actually thos is helpful as I get to access to the control I want, but it doesn't tell me how to modify it - ie an equivalent for br['control'] = 'my value'":

```
forms[N].controls[n] = myValue
```

Copying from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359817/how-do-you-select-choices-in-a-form-using-python): Read [this tutorial](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html).

The basic idea is that you can get the control by index and set any legal value that you want to it directly

Comment: Actually thos is helpful as I get to access to the control I want, but it doesn't tell me how to modify it - ie an equivalent for br['control'] = 'my value'

Comment: after your edit: I am trying this line, but it has no effect. Indeed, I don't see how we could "map it back" to the browser object.

Comment: Ahh! you'd have to `form = br.select_form(nr = N)`, and then `form.controls[n] = myVal` and `form.submit()` (or is it `br.submit()`? I can never remember). That should handle the mapping back

Comment: If I do    form = br.select_form(nr = N), the form is of type 'NoneType', and thereforme doesn't have a 'controls' attribute. Really I am lost with this problem of mapping back the unnamed controls to my browser object :(

Comment: Are you sure that there are `N` forms on the page? I have a feeling you might be asking for the Nth form, when there are fewer forms on the page.

Comment: Yes. As a test, I ran: 
    form = br.select_form(nr=0)
    print dir(form)
I don't get an attribute 'controls'. It's still a 'NoneType' for nr=0.

Comment: Try finding that form in HTML code and see what it looks like. Perhaps mechanize identifies things as forms that we don't consider to be forms (I'm really confused too - I'm just grabbing at straws here)